# How can i use different type only one column in mui datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, material-design, mui-datatable

I am using material ui datagrid. I can specify a type for each column. example boolean,date,number. But I have a problem. I want to use different types in a column.For example, I want the first line of the column to be type number and the second line to be boolean.

### How can i use different type only one column in mui datagrid ?
example:

### editableColumn

### type:number

### type:date

### type:boolean

number
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I used renderCell when defining columns. I wrote textfields for different data types in each row using if and else. I think this is not the right solution but it will fix the problem temporarily.

Comment: just using renderCell causes errors. Besides that I added renderEditCell. Both completely solved my problem. I used onCellEditCommit in datagrid to save data to redux